# Redis Won't Start Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5

Tags: redis

My working and functional redis server 5.0.7 installation on Ubuntu 20.04, simply refuses to start without any changes having be made to the config file.   It is identical to a config on a different different server running redis that starts, therefore I think the error message is systemd related

```
● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-07-30 23:09:49 HKT; 32s ago
       Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
             man:redis-server(1)
    Process: 8141 ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

redis-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
redis-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Failed to start Advanced key-value store.
redis-server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Stopped Advanced key-value store.
redis-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
redis-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Failed to start Advanced key-value store.
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: did you confirm by running redis manually?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1052285/cant-initialize-redis-as-a-systemd-service-supervised-systemd-on-ubuntu-serve check this

Comment: @VeKe thanks for the reply.   The problem has been resolved see:
https://superuser.com/questions/1734474/systemd-refuses-to-start-redis-server/1735884#1735884